# Hardware question; booting ubuntu off of USB flash drive?

Tags: live-usb

I'm currently running ubuntu off of a USB 3.0 flash drive on my laptop, and I have another USB 3.0 flash drive I use for storing larger files that I need to access and whatnot. But the issue is that both of the usb 3.0 flash drives don't fit next to each other at all, so I'm forced to use another usb 2.0 port located in a different spot on my laptop. Now my question is that if I use a USB 3.0 hub will that slow my connections down at all? or cause some sort of interference?

Another question I had which I was unable to find anywhere on the internet is if there was a USB 3.0 hub with more than one upstream connection?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use usb 3.0 speed, then get a usb 3 hub. A hub should not affect performance.

Generally we do not do hardware recommendations here, there are several options I saw on a casual search.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'm just going to make my own rig using two usb 3.0 extensions for fun :)